# How to get python code to run as a lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use this code as a lambda function so it will print the text as the output but I can't seem to figure it out. The lambda should be invoked in the event any of the values stored in critical_count, medium_count, or high_count exceed the values stored in CRITICAL, MEDIUM OR HIGH.

I have tried printing them directly but that doesn't work. I trying making them into variables but that didn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    CRITICAL = 0
    MEDIUM = 1
    HIGH = 0

    f = open('ECR_scan.json', )
    test = json.loads(f)


    resource = test["resources"][0]

    finding_severity_counts = test["detail"]["finding-severity-counts"]

    if "CRITICAL" in finding_severity_counts:
        critical_count = finding_severity_counts["CRITICAL"]
        if critical_count > CRITICAL:
            print("Resource {} has {} critical findings".format(resource, critical_count))
        
    if "MEDIUM" in finding_severity_counts:
        medium_count = finding_severity_counts["MEDIUM"]
        f medium_count > MEDIUM:
            print("Resource {} has {} medium findings".format(resource, medium_count))
        
    if "HIGH" in finding_severity_counts:
        high_count = finding_severity_counts["HIGH"]
        if high_count > HIGH:
            print("Resource {} has {} high findings".format(resource, high_count))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body':
```

Here is the json file I am envoking as well

```
    "version": "0",
    "id": "85fc3613-e913-7fc4-a80c-a3753e4aa9ae",
    "detail-type": "ECR Image Scan",
    "source": "aws.ecr",
    "account":
        "123456789012",
    "time": "2019-10-29T02:36:48Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repo"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "scan-status": "COMPLETE",
        "repository-name": "my-repo",
        "finding-severity-counts": {
            "CRITICAL": 10,
            "MEDIUM": 9
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use this code as a lambda function" Can you show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is `ECR_scan.json`? How is this information meant to be getting to the Lambda function? How is the Lambda function being invoked?

Comment: I am trying to print the returns of the if statements as the lambda's output.

Comment: The ECR_scan is the json file at the bottom of the question. It is in a separate file I am invoking in the code. I am reading the values of CRITICAL, MEDIUM, and HiGH and checking if they are greater than or less than a threshold value. I want to print the output of that as the lambda's output. The lambda will be invoked in the event any of the values exceed the threshold values.

Comment: How is the lambda function invoked?

Comment: I added how the lambda should be invoked

Comment: You will need to invoke the function as [filename].lambda_handler - e.g. my_script.lambda_handler

Also why not put a print statement to ensure the process writes out something before the if conditions.

What are you also getting in the lambda output and logs?

Comment: Actually, you _didn't_ add how the Lambda should be invoked. Are you invoking it from API Gateway, an Application Load balancer, or via direct API call? If the last, please show the code that invokes the Lambda.

Comment: Also, what does CloudWatch Logs show for your Lambda invocation? Is it running to completion? Is there an error?